# Multiple overlapping regex matches instead of one

Tags: regex, r

Consider this string:

```
data <- "1-FA-1-I2-1-I2-1-I2-1-EX-1-I2-1-I3-1-FA-1-I1-1-I2-1-TR-1-I1-1-I2-1-FA-1-I3-1-I1-1-FA-1-FA-1-NR-1-I3-1-I2-1-TR-1-I1-1-I2-1-I1-1-I2-1-FA-1-I2-1-I1-1-I3-1-FA-1-QU-1-I1-1-I2-1-I2-1-I2-1-NR-1-I2-1-I2-1-NR-1-I1-1-I2-1-I1-1-NR-1-I3-1-QU-1-I2-1-I3-1-QU-1-NR-1-I2-1-I1-1-NR-1-QU-1-QU-1-I2-1-I1-1-EX"
```

and this regex:

```
"(I3).{1,}(I3)"
```

This would match the section between the first `I3` and the last `I3`. However, how should I modify the regex to match each separate section beginning and ending with `I3`? E.g.

```
I3-1-FA-1-I1-1-I2-1-TR-1-I1-1-I2-1-FA-1-I3
I3-1-I1-1-FA-1-FA-1-NR-1-I3
I3-1-I2-1-TR-1-I1-1-I2-1-I1-1-I2-1-FA-1-I2-1-I1-1-I3
I3-1-FA-1-QU-1-I1-1-I2-1-I2-1-I2-1-NR-1-I2-1-I2-1-NR-1-I1-1-I2-1-I1-1-NR-1-I3
I3-1-QU-1-I2-1-I3
```

Comment: `/I3.+?I3/`, perhaps?

Comment: @Biffen: That gets 1/2 of the necessary matches, but since it uses the last `I3` of the first match as the endpoint of that match, it cannot get the second stretch between the second and third `I3`, but skips straight to the 3rd required match.

Comment: Ah, good point. A look-around should do it, as suggested in one of the answers.

Answer (score 3):

Use  non-greedy form and a positive lookahead.

```
"(?=(I3.+?I3))"
```

Fetch the string you want from group index 1. Lookaheads helps to do overlapping matches. In `R` you must enable `perl=TRUE` parameter.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lK4eY3/1)

Comment: also gives me `Invalid regexp` in `R`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `strsplit` with `gsub` like this:

```
data <- "1-FA-1-I2-1-I2-1-I2-1-EX-1-I2-1-I3-1-FA-1-I1-1-I2-1-TR-1-I1-1-I2-1-FA-1-I3-1-I1-1-FA-1-FA-1-NR-1-I3-1-I2-1-TR-1-I1-1-I2-1-I1-1-I2-1-FA-1-I2-1-I1-1-I3-1-FA-1-QU-1-I1-1-I2-1-I2-1-I2-1-NR-1-I2-1-I2-1-NR-1-I1-1-I2-1-I1-1-NR-1-I3-1-QU-1-I2-1-I3-1-QU-1-NR-1-I2-1-I1-1-NR-1-QU-1-QU-1-I2-1-I1-1-EX"
data <- gsub(".*?(I3.*?)(?=I3)","\\1I3§",data,perl=T)
strsplit(gsub("[^§]*$", "", data),"§")
```

The `.*?(I3.*?)(?=I3)` regex (with `\\1I3§` replacement) will remove all text before `I3...I3`, add a fake symbol `§` (you may use any you do not use), add a backup `I3` for us to have complete `I3` enclosed entries in the output, and then a second `gsub` will remove the trailing unnecessary part from the string. `strsplit` will do the final part - fetch you your expected results.

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/UxFnhY)

Output:

```
[1] "I3-1-FA-1-I1-1-I2-1-TR-1-I1-1-I2-1-FA-1-I3"                                   
[2] "I3-1-I1-1-FA-1-FA-1-NR-1-I3"                                                  
[3] "I3-1-I2-1-TR-1-I1-1-I2-1-I1-1-I2-1-FA-1-I2-1-I1-1-I3"                         
[4] "I3-1-FA-1-QU-1-I1-1-I2-1-I2-1-I2-1-NR-1-I2-1-I2-1-NR-1-I1-1-I2-1-I1-1-NR-1-I3"
[5] "I3-1-QU-1-I2-1-I3"
```